# converting bytearray to dictionary ( using c-structure)

Tags: python, dictionary, data-conversion

I have a byte array and convert it with the help of c-structures to
objects.

Also the revers way works.

Now I'm looking for a pythonic way to convert the object to a dictionary.

I foud a module called dictfier, which nearly does the job.
But for some items ( a byte-array that is a string) will not work sufficent, cause dictifier
creates one member for each byte.

Here is my code

```
import ctypes as ct
import struct


class MyNestedStruct(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('val10', ct.c_int32),
                ('val11', ct.c_uint8 * 8),


class MyStruct(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('val1', ct.c_int32),
                ('val2', ct.c_int32),
                ('val3', ct.c_int32),
                ('val4', ct.c_int32),
                ('my_nest', MyNestedStruct))


def vdd_decode_from_bytes(bin_bytes):
    return MyStruct.from_buffer_copy(bin_bytes)

data = bytes.fromhex('acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001')
s = vdd_decode_from_bytes(data)
print(s)       # via __repr__
print(s.val1)  # still access individual values
print(s.val2)
print(s.val3)
print(s.val4)
print(s.my_nest)
print(bytes(s).hex()) # convert back to byte stream (shown as hex)
```

So with s I have an object/structure were I can access the subelements
s.val1, s.my_nest.val11

So how can I convert this to a dictionary?

```
s['val1']
s[my_nest']['val10']
s[my_nest']['val11'] ?
```

And val11 is for example a string. So how to generate a string.
Using dictifi I get s[my_nest']['val11'][0]...s[my_nest']['val11'][7]

So that is my code

Try to useknown methods to serialize objets, or the module dicifi

Comment: The fields of an object are available in `obj.__dict__`.

Comment: yes I know. But on some reason ( I'm not shure if it relies on the c-struct) the __dict__is empty

Comment: Do you want a dictionary (a Python dict), or do you want to be able to access and change the packed fields in the struct using the mapping notation (like dictionaries), using `s['val1`]`  instead of `s.val1` ?
Both things are feasible, but they are different things.

Comment: 2nd one. Actually I have binary data->convert to c-like structures
What I wnat to achieve binary data->convert to mapping notation ( s['val1'] ) and then also backwards.
With dictifi I have it, but not the backwards way.
Also dicitfi has the problem with that byte arrays thet were a string ( for example)